# Modifying OWS Server info with qgis api

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, wms, wfs, qgis-server

i'm looking for a way to disable/enable modify OWS Server tab in project properties. Is it possible using just qgis python api ? 
[image]
Currently i'm building web application, which provides spatial services with qgis server. And i'm looking for a way to manage this services. Is it only way to do this ? Any other ideas ?